# Wrong number of arguments: called-interactively-p, 1

Tags: emacs, centos

```
~/.emacs

;; http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d//ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

when I load emacs, it complains the error as "Wrong number of arguments: called-interactively-p, 1". In other words, emacs finds error until the line `(ac-config-default)`.

when I check the file .emacs.d/auto-complete.elc, I found the string "called-interactively-p".

Question> I have used the same setting for ubuntu without problems. Now I am switching centos 6.2. Is there a way that I fix this problem?

emacs --debug-init shows the following errors:

͂

Comment: You did not paste the error message correctly.

Comment: If you have the same .emacs with the same version of auto-complete-config, I would guess that you have different versions of Emacs on the two machines. What does M-x emacs-version say on both computers?

Comment: The key difference is that one runs on ubuntu latest version and the other runs on centos lastest version. The version of emacs is latest one

Comment: Instead of using that auto package, you can try this [one](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-i386/emacs-auto-complete-el-1.3.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm.html)  on CentOS 6. It works very well for me.

Comment: "The version of emacs is latest one" is not a useful answer to the question "What does M-x emacs-version say on both computers?"

Answer (score 12):

It is worth mentioning that this error may arise if you move your emacs.d directory from one machine to another.

If this is the case, removing the compiled *.elc files should do the trick.

Comment: this fixed my issue too - added to my .gitignore for the future.

Answer (score 4):

In recent Emacsen, `called-interactively-p` requires an argument.

Do <kbd>C-h f ac-quick-help RET</kbd>, then replace `(called-interactively-p)` by `(called-interactively-p 'any)` and recompile/reload.  Or send this bug to the package's author.

Answer (score 2):

[ As I mentioned recently in some other stackoverflow question, it is *strongly* recommended to not put "~/.emacs.d" in your `load-path` since the ~/.emacs.d directory can/will hold configuration files whose name clashes with real emacs packages.  I.e. put the auto-complete files in a *sub*directory of ~/.emacs.d.  ]

Your error looks very strange: while `called-interactively-p` is declared in Emacs-23 as taking exactly 1 argument, it actually accepts 0 arguments as well (to ease up the pain for external packages that want to support both Emacs-22 and Emacs-23).
So seems to be something else in your config which somehow redefines called-interactively-p.

Comment: Would it be worth having an automated warning message if a load path ending in "/.emacs.d" is observed, as a prevention measure against that sort of issue?